# Asp Mvc 5 Redirect to other web site in HttpApplication event handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I need to redirect authorized user to other web site in case of some extra conditions, what is the best event in global asax (HttpApplication) for it ?
Is AuthorizeRequest  event fine for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply redirect based on IsAuthorized in your controller?

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity.IsAuthorized)
{
  //redirect somewhere  
}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of controllers ? and they is not inheritance from some custom controller ?